# how to set NSMutableParagraphStyle firstLineHeadIndent for just first paragraph

Tags: ios, nsparagraphstyle

I want set `firstLineHeadIndent` for only first paragraph for a multi-paragraph `UILabel`, how can I do

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStype = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStype.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0f;
[att addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStype range:NSMakeRange(0, att.length)];
```

Comment: Use something other than `att.length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use smaller range:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStype = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStype.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0f;
[att addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStype range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```